# How can removing final keyword change the way a program behaves?

Tags: java, final

This question is not primarily about Strings. Out of academic curiosity I would like to know how the `final` modifier on a variable can change the behaviour a program. The following example shows it is possible.

These lines print `true`

```
final String x = "x";
System.out.println(x + x == "xx");
```

but these lines print `false`

```
String x = "x";
System.out.println(x + x == "xx");
```

Apart from `String` interning, are there any other things that can cause the behaviour of a program to change if the modifier `final` is removed from a variable declaration? I am assuming that the program compiles with or without the modifier.

Please don't vote to close it as duplicate of [Comparing strings with == which are declared final in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418427/comparing-strings-with-which-are-declared-final-in-java). I understand the `String`s example.

I'm asking if there are any *other* reasons removing a `final` modifier can make a difference. Please can someone link to an answer or answer the question. Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418427/comparing-strings-with-which-are-declared-final-in-java

Comment: Being `final` is not enough, it has to be *compilation-time-constant*. Example: if you have method `public static String method(int i) { return i % 2 == 0 ? "x" : "y"; }` and you declare your `x` as `final String x = method(0);` (or maybe even `final String x = method(new Random().nextInt(100));`) compiler can't treat is as compilation-time-constant so it can't do concatenation at compilation time which would let `x+x` become `"x"+"x"` expression evaluated to `"xx"` literal.

Comment: I didn't downvote, that answer explains how `final` makes it compile time constant and that explains how it gets cached into string pool

Comment: reopened <!----------->

Comment: Can you add more details about this part: "are there any other things that can cause the behaviour of a program to change if the modifier final is removed from a variable declaration"? What kind of change we are talking about? BTW: "But my question isn't about Strings" if you wouldn't say I wouldn't know it... maybe consider adding this information at top of your question so person who will read your examples would know that String is not *mandatory*.

Comment: I'm guessing we're talking about local variables only, not fields.

Comment: @biziclop I was thinking mainly about local variables, but do you have an example with fields?

Comment: @pbabcdefp Off the top of my head `final` fields are guaranteed to be visible by all threads after object construction, while non-final fields are not.

Comment: @pbabcdefp You can take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) too, in particular the paragraph about `constant variable`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `final` modifier only ensures that the variable is [definitely assigned](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html), and prohibits any reassignment to and from that variable.

The only special cases that can be observed are [expressly stated in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4-300):

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a constant variable.
>
> Whether a variable is a constant variable or not may have implications with respect to class initialization (§12.4.1), binary compatibility (§13.1, §13.4.9) and definite assignment (§16).

There's a decent amount of JLS reading, and to cover the main point:  **By [JLS §13.4.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9)**, you will **not** encounter any ill effects upon *removing* the `final` modifier.

However, **[by JLS 17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html)**, if you rely on the guarantee of a thread only seeing the definitely assigned variables in an object that it can observe, then removing the `final` variable will cause those variables to no longer be visible to another thread.

---

So, if we look at [class initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) first, there are rules surrounding class initialization if the field is static and *not* a constant variable:

> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - T is a class and a static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).

In [JLS §13.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1), it is spelled out that changing a field to `final` can break [binary compatibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9):

> References to fields that are constant variables (§4.12.4) are resolved at compile time to the constant value that is denoted. No reference to such a field should be present in the code in a binary file (except in the class or interface containing the field, which will have code to initialize it). Such a field must always appear to have been initialized (§12.4.2); the default initial value for the type of such a field must never be observed. See §13.4.9 for a discussion.

From 13.4.9:

> If a field that was not declared final is changed to be declared
>   final, then it can break compatibility with pre-existing binaries that
>   attempt to assign new values to the field.
>
> Deleting the keyword final or changing the value to which a field is
>   initialized does not break compatibility with existing binaries.
>
> If a field is a constant variable (§4.12.4), then deleting the keyword
>   final or changing its value will not break compatibility with
>   pre-existing binaries by causing them not to run, but they will not
>   see any new value for the usage of the field unless they are
>   recompiled. This is true even if the usage itself is not a
>   compile-time constant expression (§15.28).
>
> This result is a side-effect of the decision to support conditional
>   compilation, as discussed at the end of §14.21.

So from that alone, be careful about suddenly changing fields to `final`.  *Removing* the field is **safe**.

...but that only applies to a single-threaded world.  From [JLS 17.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5):

> Fields declared final are initialized once, but never changed under
>   normal circumstances. The detailed semantics of final fields are
>   somewhat different from those of normal fields. In particular,
>   compilers have a great deal of freedom to move reads of final fields
>   across synchronization barriers and calls to arbitrary or unknown
>   methods. Correspondingly, compilers are allowed to keep the value of a
>   final field cached in a register and not reload it from memory in
>   situations where a non-final field would have to be reloaded.
>
> final fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable
>   objects without synchronization. A thread-safe immutable object is
>   seen as immutable by all threads, even if a data race is used to pass
>   references to the immutable object between threads. This can provide
>   safety guarantees against misuse of an immutable class by incorrect or
>   malicious code. final fields must be used correctly to provide a
>   guarantee of immutability.
>
> An object is considered to be completely initialized when its
>   constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an
>   object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed
>   to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final
>   fields.

So, if your program relies on the above guarantee for it to function normally, then removing the `final` keyword will have consequences in threading.

Comment: Except if you rely on the visibility guarantees for `final` fields, in which case removing the `final` keyword isn't safe either.

Comment: Do you have a reference to those visibility guarantees you're talking about?

Comment: `An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values for that object's final fields.`

Comment: While I think that lends itself to the discussion of definite assignment, it'd be worth adding to the answer.  Thanks for that.  I'll add it in when I get near a machine.