# why the output is not excepted (true) if two string has same reference?

Tags: java, string

Yesterday this Question asked by Interviewer what is the output for that line.

```
public class StringTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String s1 = "abc";
      String s2 = "abc";
      String s3 = s1+s2;
      String s4 = s1+s2;

      //check s1 == s2
      System.out.println(s1==s2);

      //check s3 == s4
      System.out.println(s3==s4);
  }
}
```

when i looked at this question then thinking how the easy question asked by interviewer. I told him output `s1==s2` and `s3==s4` will return `true` and `true`and i was very confident.
Suddenly he said no thats the wrong output then i thinking he might be joking or trying to loosing my confidence, but till the end he said its wrong.
When i checked the output was `true` and `false` .
I also thinking how it is possible please solve my confusion by giving a appropriate answer.
thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the very first of it's kind question on String's. Thankyou.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ  forgot the /s

Comment: @amit i can't find my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @amit why r u marked this duplicate .... please do check for this type of question explanation is not given.

Comment: Because I find `s1+s2` and `new String(s1)` to be basically the same concept, and the later is answered with details.

Comment: There were other questions with the same topic (concatenation of string literals and `==` returns false), but I couldn't find any of them. May they have bad title so OP couldn't find them either :D. Edit: mhh, maybe this is a good one: [Comparing strings with == which are declared final in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19418427)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`s1+s2` is not known at compile time so it is calculated at runtime and creates a new object, which is different each time it is run. If you change s1 and s2 to be final, the compiler will inline the constants and you will get true for `s3==s4`.

```
  final String s1 = "abc";
  final String s2 = "abc";
  String s3 = s1+s2; // compiler replaces with "abcabc"
  String s4 = s1+s2; // compiler replaces with "abcabc"

  //check s1 == s2
  System.out.println(s1==s2);

  //check s3 == s4
  System.out.println(s3==s4); // is now true.
```

OR

```
  String s1 = "abc";
  String s2 = "abc";
  String s3 = (s1+s2).intern(); // use the string literal pool
  String s4 = (s1+s2).intern();

  //check s1 == s2
  System.out.println(s1==s2);

  //check s3 == s4
  System.out.println(s3==s4); // is now true.
```

BUT

```
  String s1 = "abc";
  String s2 = "abc";
  // String s3 = s1+s2;
  String s3 = new StringBuilder().append(s1).append(s2).toString();
  // String s4 = s1+s2;
  String s4 = new StringBuilder().append(s1).append(s2).toString();

  //check s3 == s4
  System.out.println(s3==s4); // different objects.
```

Answer (score -1):

Because strings are immutable and are ubiquitous in programming, the JVM uses a
unique instance for string literals with the same character sequence in order to improve efficiency and save memory. Such an instance is called an interned string.
Lets say:

```
String s1 = "xyz";
String s2 = "xyz";
```

In the preceding statements, `s1` and `s2` refer to the same interned string—"xyz"—so `s1 == s2` is true. This is not the case with `s3` and `s4`. You can read more about interned Strings on Google.

Comment: why not s3 ==s4 plz give me reason not reference