# Java String equality example

Tags: java, string

Sorry beforehand for a basic question but can someone please explain me why:

```
String s = "lo";
String str7 = "Hel" + s;
String str8 = "He" + "llo";
System.out.println("str7 == str8 is " + (str7 == str8));
```

outputs false.
I thought that str7 and str8 both point to the same object in String pool specifically because Strings are immutable.

Am I wrong?
Are str7 and str8 are both not in the pool but in the heap? Why?

Can you please provide me with example of some String manipulation when the result would be indeed the same immutable string from the string pool?

PS:

```
String str9 = "He" +"llo";
System.out.println("str8 == str9 is " + (str9 == str8));
```

outputs true

Comment: @RajithPemabandu: But the question is specifically about the underlying representation; using `equals` is meant to avoid  those very details.

Comment: The reason why str8 == str9 is compiler optimization

Comment: Related: [Comparing strings with == which are declared final in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418427/comparing-strings-with-which-are-declared-final-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

Your understanding is correct in case of pool where all the literals goes into strings pool.

And the confusion arises when you do the concatenation. Here is the two points to note.

1) If the String resolves at compile time, yes it syncs with String pool and uses the same literals. For ex

```
String str7 = "Helllo";
String str8 = "He" + "llo";
```

Note that both are plain literals. Hence no runtime conversions etc.

2) If the String resolves at run time,  it resolves to a a new string at runtime and differs with any other other string unless you use .equals method to compare its content.

```
String str7 = "Hel" + s;
String str8 = "He" + "llo";
System.out.println("str7 == str8 is " + (str7 == str8)); //false
```

In this case concat strings with (+) operator, JVM returns `new StringBuilder(string...).toString()` cause one is a plain literal and other is a variable.

Look at the [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

**Questions from comment :**

> does it mean that in case the string is produced as the product of concatenation of literals then the result is always the same string in the pool?

Yes it is.Remember that concatenation  you mean by compile time resolved expression (aka constant expression) and not Runtime.

> And when we concatenate string literal with string object then the resulting string is always a new string object built by means of StringBuilder under the hood?

Yes a new String been returned. Attached JVM link confirms you that.

Comment: Your answer is perfect, complete and easy to understand thumb up !

Comment: Thank you Suresh.
To make a final point, does it mean that in case the string is produced as the product of concatenation of literals then the result is always the same string in the pool? And when we concatenate string literal with string object then the resulting string is always a new string object built by means of StringBuilder under the hood?

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov Edited my answer with given questions.

Answer (score 1):

`str7` and `str8` are both in the pool, but they are not the same string.  That is, they are different versions of the same sequence of characters.

Think about the performance hit you'd get if the VM had to scan the whole pool each time a string was created to see if another string with the same sequence of characters was already present.

In your new example, you are building both `str8` and `str9` from the same underlying strings, so the compiler can more readily tell the result of each is the same and can re-use that entry in the pool.

Comment: Sorry Scott - I'm totally confused and overwhelmed.
What does it mean exactly "different versions of the same sequence of characters" residing both in the pool?

As to scanning the whole pool I thought that was exactly the point/purpose of having the String pool.

Comment: The purpose of the pool is to re-use strings when it has recognized that it can do so; the compiler balances the cost of finding matching strings (which usually fails) with the benefit of re-using them.

Comment: You seem to understand what "different versions of the same sequence of characters" means well enough to argue about it: two distinct strings taking up different locations in memory which happen to have the same characters in the same order.

Comment: This is incorrect.  `str7` is NOT in the string pool.  It is not the result of a *constant expression* and it hasn't been explicitly intern'd.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "lo";
String str7 = "Hel" + s;
String str8 = "He" + "llo";
String str9 = "He" + "llo";
```

The object that `s` refers to is the String object that represents the "lo" literal.  It is in the string pool.

The objects that `str8` and `str9` refer to are the result of evaluating an expression that is a *constant expression*.  Therefore they are in the string pool.  And in fact, since the expressions evaluate to "the same" string, `str8` and `str9` refer to the same actual `String` object.

The object that `str7` refers to is the result of evaluating an expression that is NOT a constant expression.  Therefore it is NOT in the string pool.

The ultimate reason why `"Hel" + s` is not a *constant expression* here is that `s` was not declared as `final`.

---

**The thing to remember** here is that String objects are only allocated in the String pool in two circumstances:

1. If they are the result of evaluating a *constant expression*, or
2. If they are explicitly produced using the `String.intern()` method.

String literals are a sub-case of *constant expression*.

For a more detailed explanation of what a *constant expression* is, see the Java Language Specification - [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) (constant expression) and [JLS 4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) (constant variable).

Any string that is not produced in one of those circumstances not in the string pool.

Comment: Thank you for the precise explanation, Stephen

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke [`String#intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--), then the compiler will scan the `String` pool and perform as you seem to have expected. That is,

```
String s = "lo";
String str7 = ("Hel" + s).intern();
String str8 = ("He" + "llo").intern();
System.out.println("str7 == str8 is " + (str7 == str8));
```

Outputs

```
str7 == str8 is true
```

There are two things causing this behavior

1. `String` is immutable, so using `+` necessitates creating new `String`(s)
2. `String` concatenation is usually implemented with `StringBuilder` - that is `new StringBuilder("Hel").append(s).toString()` and `new StringBuilder("He").append("llo").toString()` and `StringBuilder` *does not* scan the `String` intern pool.

Comment: I know the meaning of intern(), thanks
The question is why those two Strings, s7 and s8, are pointing to different strings in the same place - string pool

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov I hope my two bullet points clear up the *why*.

Comment: .. Stephen C explains why s7 and s8 point actually to different places