# Comparing string references

Tags: java, string, reference, heap-memory, string-interning

I'm trying to understand reference comparing in Java.
Let's assume we have the following main code:

```
public static void main (String args[]) {
   String str1 = "Love!";  
   String str2 = "Love!";
   String str3 = new String("Love!");  
   String str4 = new String("Love!");
   String str5 = "Lov"+ "e!";  
   String str6 = "Lo" + "ve!";  
   String s = "e!";
   String str7 = "Lov"+ s;  
   String str8 = "Lo" + "ve!";
   String str9 = str1;
}
```

I understand that `str1 == str2 == str5 == str6 == str8 == str9` and all of them are the same reference to the common pool. (value "Love!").
`s` is a reference to the common pool as well, but it refers the value "e!"

I understand also that `str1 != s`.

I know that `str3`, `str4` are references to the HEAP, and each of them is a different Object. `str3 != str4`.

I do NOT understand why **`str1 != str7`,** and I would love to get an explanation.

Comment: If you "understand" that `str1 == str4`, then you need to forget what you think you know, because it is not. `str3`, `str4`, and `str7` are all 3 independent objects.

Comment: yes my bad. it's in the heap. str3, str4 in the heap. sorry

Comment: Simple answer: the compiler treats it specially when you concatenate two strings and the compiler knows what those strings are (because they're string literals or `static final` constants).  `s` is a variable, which is why `str7` doesn't fall into that case.

Comment: String concatenation of *literals* and/or *compile-time constants* are applied by the compiler, so the concatenated result is added to the string pool. Concatenation involving non-constant variables will always create a new string. Since `s` is not a constant, `str7` is a new string.

Comment: ajb, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Andreas I win by 18 seconds.  But I think last time we both posted virtually identical comments, you won by 30 seconds, so I guess you're still ahead by a little bit.

Comment: @Andreas don't be mad at me about str4, it was a typo.

Comment: Related: [Comparing strings with == which are declared final in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418427/comparing-strings-with-which-are-declared-final-in-java)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In

```
String s = "e!";
String str7 = "Lov"+ s;
```

While `"e!"` is a constant expression, `s` is *not* a constant variable [(JLS §4.12.4)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4); therefore, `"Lov" + s`, which references `s`, cannot be a constant expression [(JLS §15.28)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). In order for a variable like `s` to be a constant variable, it needs to be both `final` and initialized from a constant expression.

If you had written

```
final String s = "e!";
String str7 = "Lov" + s;
```

then `str1 == str7` would have been true.