# How intern works in case of Concat

Tags: java, string, constants, pool

```
String a = "x";
String b = a + "y";
String c = "xy";
System.out.println(b==c);
```

Why it prints **false**?

As per my understanding "xy"(which is a+"y") will be interned and when variable c is created compiler will check if literal "xy" is present in String constant pool if present then it will assign same reference to c.

Note : I am not asking equals() vs == operator.

Comment: `"xy"` is interned, but the result of `a+"y"` isn't, nor is the interned `"xy"` used as that result, because `a` isn't final.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing strings with == which are declared final in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418427/comparing-strings-with-which-are-declared-final-in-java)

Comment: Besides the other answers: also try to,avoid to rely on it. It is brittle if code is reused.

Answer (score 1):

If a String is formed by concatenating two String literals it will also be interned.

```
String a = "x";
String b = a + "y"; // a is not a string literal, so no interning
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
String b = "x" + "y"; // on the other hand, "x" is a string literal
String c = "xy";

System.out.println( b == c ); // true
```

Here is a commonly found example on string interning in Java

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hello = "Hello", lo = "lo";

        System.out.print((hello == "Hello") + " ");
        System.out.print((Other.hello == hello) + " ");
        System.out.print((other.Other.hello == hello) + " ");
        System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+"lo")) + " ");
        System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+lo)) + " ");
        System.out.println(hello == ("Hel"+lo).intern());
    }
}

class Other { static String hello = "Hello"; }
```

followed by it's output

```
true
true
true
true
false
true
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `"xy"`, as is assigned to `c`, is added to the string pool (used by `intern`) straight away is because the value is known at compile time.

The value `a+"y"` is not known at compile time, but only at run time.  Because `intern` is an expensive operation, that is not normally done unless the developer codes for it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Ok, so variable b will be present in stack where as c will be referring to string constant pool ?

Comment: Technically, `b` will refer to a string that's in the heap, but otherwise yes.