# difference between string and final string

Tags: java, string

```
public class ExampleString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="u cannot change me!";
        String s2="u cannot change me!";
        String s3="u cannot"+" change me!";
        String s4="u cannot";
        String s5=s4+" change me!";
        final String s6="u cannot";
        String s7=s6+" change me!";

        System.out.println("s1==s2 "+(s1==s2));//true
        System.out.println("s1==s3 "+(s1==s3));//true
        System.out.println("s1==s5 "+(s1==s5));//false  why  it is false
        System.out.println("s1==s7 "+(s1==s7));//true   why  it is true
        System.out.println("s4==s6 "+(s4==s6));//true 
      //  System.out.println("s5 "+s5);
       // System.out.println("s7 "+s7);
        System.out.println("s5==s7 "+(s5==s7));//false  why                     
    }
}
```

in case of s5 am doing  concatenation but it will give ouput false
in case of s7 also am doing concatenation it will give true.
am declaring s6 am declaring string as final string am getting true 
my question is why it is giving like that or what is the difference between them

Comment: i want to know difference between string and final string in case of  why s1==s5 false and why s1==s7 true

Comment: @Anon this question is about comparing two reference of String object. How does it relevant to look into equals method?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418427/comparing-strings-with-which-are-declared-final-in-java) explains the difference `final` makes.

Comment: @IndraNandu Do you want to test if the String contents is the same OR if the String object/reference itself is the same?

Comment: in case of .equals(); it will check content comparison .but hear content is same in all cases . so it will give true .but i want to know about reference comparison(==)  how it will stored like

Comment: in case of s1,s5,s7 content is same but in case of s1,s7 referring same object but in case of s5 it's is referring  different object

Comment: For (s4==s6) check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3801355/6413377)

Comment: s4==s6 that's ok one is string and another one is final string but both are refering same object

Comment: @IndraNandu Yes and the linked answer tells you why they are the same object.