# Why does comparing equal strings with "==" work in one case and not the other?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String fName = "James";
        String lName = "Gosling";
        String name1 = fName + lName;
        String name2 = fName + "Gosling";
        String name3 = "James" + "Gosling";
        System.out.println(name1 == name2);
        System.out.println(name2 == name3);
    }
}
```

output:

```
false 
true
```

Can anyone if possible please explain this output with reason?

Comment: Probably you won't see the answer to your question directly in the linked answer. Anyway, the point of your code is that `fName` is `final` whend `lName` is not. That means the compiler cannot internal the String reference from `lName`.

Comment: Yes, this was clearly NOT a duplicate of the "How do I compare strings in Java" question.  I've reopened it, so that @PeterMmm can turn his comment into an answer if he so wishes.  PeterMmm, if you don't write an answer, I will, because this is actually an interesting question.

Comment: It isn't a dupe of #513832, but it is an exact dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47959691/difference-between-string-and-final-string and nearly of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418427/comparing-strings-with-which-are-declared-final-in-java @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: Perfect!  The OP should be satisfied with the answers to those questions.