# String Literal and Object Literal comparison

Tags: java, string, object, equals, string-literals

I come up with the scenario & can't understand the logic behind it ? **I understood the first one only**, rest two unable to understand ? Please explain how internally it work?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "Karan";
        Object o = "Karan";

        System.out.println(s.equals(o));         // True
        System.out.println(o.equals(s));        // True 
        System.out.println(s == o);            // True
    }
}
```

Comment: because both are string literals and pointed to same reference in string constant pool

Comment: There is no 'object literal', both are string literals (which due to the string constant pool are resolved to the same instance), one just happens to be assigned to a variable typed as `Object` instead of `String`. The object itself however is still a `String`.

Comment: Can you be bit more precise? What exactly is confusing and why?

Comment: @Deadpool but we are creating String of Object type? then how it will point to SCP ?

Comment: @Pshemo I don't understand why Object type of String pointing to SCP ?

Comment: "but we are creating String of Object type" no, in case of `Object o = "Karan";` we are creating (or actually reusing from String Constant Pool) *object* of String type and we are storing *reference* to that object in *variable* of Object type.

Comment: Maybe this will help a little for a start: [What is the difference between a variable, object, and reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32010172)

Comment: duplicate of this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @MandarDharurkar no, that is not a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the *static type* of an object and the *dynamic type* of a variable.

The static type is the type known at compile time. For `Object o = "Karan";`, the static type is the one at the left of `o`, i.e. `Object`. Now, one could ask why that is the case since at compile-time, it can be inferred that `o` is a `String`. Well if we consider something like

```
Object o;
if (someCondition) {
    o = "Karam";
} else {
    o = new StringBuffer();
}
```

then we cannot know whether `o` is a `String` or a `StringBuffer`, thus its static type is `Object` (since `o` is defined as `Object`).

The dynamic type is the type at runtime. In the example above, after the `if`-statement has been executed, `o` is either a `String` or a `StringBuffer`, but not both and nothing else. In your example, the dynamic type of `Object o = "Karan";` is `String`.

When variables are compared through `equals(...)`, they must have the same dynamic type in order for the comparison to return `true` (notice that this property is necessary, but not sufficient). Since `o` in your example is, in fact, a `String` AND the content is equal to `s`, `s.equals(o) == o.equals(s) == true`.

As to why `s == o` returns `true`: the question is answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59592175/using-in-java).

Comment: Technically the "static type" only matters for **variables**. *Objects* only have the dynamic type. Understanding the distinction between the object and a variable that references that object is very important for this question.

Comment: True that. I reworded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`String s = "Karan"` this is a String object referred by a String reference.

`Object o = "Karan"` this is a String object referred by an Object reference. Super class can refer to object of sub-class.

For both `s.equals(o)` and `o.equals(s)` the underlying objects `equal()` is called, since the objects are of type String (even if reference 'o' is of type Object) String's equals is called which compares the value of the string which are equal. That is what you got `true` as result.

`s == o` compares the object reference of s and o. They were created using **double quote** which uses the String pool, creates the object once and refers it again. So both s and o are exactly same String object. This makes `==` return true.