# Why cannot modify a String field with Reflection?

Tags: java, string, reflection, jvm

JDK version: 1.8.0_291

Target class:

```
package reflectionStackoverflow.test;

public class ClassA {
    private final static StringBuilder nameStringBuilder = new StringBuilder("1");
    private final static String nameString = "1";
 
    public static void printNameStringBuild() {
        System.out.println("nameStringBuilder: " + nameStringBuilder);
    }
    public static void printNameString() {
        System.out.println("nameString: " + nameString);
    }
}
```

Test Code:

```
package reflectionStackoverflow.test;

import org.junit.Test;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class ReflectionTest {
    @Test
    public void test() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        Class c = ClassA.class;

        Field nameStringBuilder = c.getDeclaredField("nameStringBuilder");
        nameStringBuilder.setAccessible(true);
        Field nameStringBuilderModifiers = nameStringBuilder.getClass().getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        nameStringBuilderModifiers.setAccessible(true);
        nameStringBuilderModifiers.setInt(nameStringBuilder, nameStringBuilder.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        nameStringBuilder.set(c, new StringBuilder("2"));
        nameStringBuilderModifiers.setInt(nameStringBuilder, nameStringBuilder.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        Field nameString = c.getDeclaredField("nameString");
        nameString.setAccessible(true);
        Field nameStringModifiers = nameString.getClass().getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        nameStringModifiers.setAccessible(true);
        nameStringModifiers.setInt(nameString, nameString.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        nameString.set(c, "2");
        nameStringModifiers.setInt(nameString, nameString.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

        ClassA.printNameStringBuild();
        ClassA.printNameString();
    }
}
```

Test result:

```
nameStringBuilder: 2
nameString: 1
```

Conclusion:

StringBuilder field can be modified with reflection, but String field can not be modified.

Question:

Why String can not be modified with reflection？

Is there any way to modify a `private final static String` value like above StringBuilder case?

Comment: Why did you tag your question "C++"?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Sry, I think this question may related to the implementation of Java and mainstream JVM is implemented with cpp, so cpper may know some of it.

Comment: `final static String nameString = "1";` is compile-time constant (it is `final` and its value is known at compilation time). This lets compiler use its value directly instead of generating call to *variable* (which speeds things up). So if you use at some point `nameString` compiler will treat it as if you written `"1"` (it is called *inlining*). So in case of `System.out.println("nameString: " + nameString);` ***compiler will generate same bytecode as if you would written `System.out.println("nameString: " + "1");`***. As you see, this bytecode no longer *depends* on `nameString`.

Comment: Changing value of `nameString` will not make `System.out.println("nameString: " + "1");` recompile to use *new value*. What you may want to do is *preventing* nameString from being compile-time constant by assigning to it value which will NOT be [constant expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). For instance you could initialize it like `private final static String nameString = new String("1");`.

Comment: This question may interest you: [Comparing strings with == which are declared final in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19418427) (it is not related to your question, but you can find some more details there about compile-time constant expressions and inlining). Also read last section of [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720) in [Change private static final field using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3301635)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change private static final field using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)

Comment: This should answer your question: [Answer about compile time constants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301818/845414)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java compiler is required (by the Java Language Specification) to inline constant variables (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1-110-C for the current version, but the same requirement was already in the [JLS for Java 1.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/binaryComp.html#78177)).

You can work around this by making `nameString` a so called "blank final" (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/html/typesValues.html#10931):

```
    private static final String nameString;
    static {
        nameString =  "1";
    }
```

*This solves your current problem*, **but** it will get you into trouble if you ever want to upgrade your Java version. Java 12 and later do no longer allow setting the `modifier` field of the `Field` class. If your code depends on this hack it will forever be locked to Java versions 11 or lower.

Update to the preceding paragraph: *In this case (only running some tests) it might solve your problem* **but**: the JVM is free to optimize the access to the field (even in the case of a blank final field it is declared as **final** and the JIT optimizer can do optimizations it cannot do with non-final fields)

To show the problem:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before:");
        System.out.println("Field1: "+Class2.getField1());
        System.out.println("Field2: "+Class2.getField2());
        System.out.println("Field3: "+Class2.getField3());
        System.out.println("Field3: "+Class2.getField3());
        System.out.println();

        Class c = Class2.class;
        Field f1 = c.getDeclaredField("field1");
        Field f2 = c.getDeclaredField("field2");
        Field f3 = c.getDeclaredField("field3");
        changeField(f1);
        changeField(f2);
        changeField(f3);

        System.out.println("After:");
        System.out.println("Field1: "+Class2.getField1());
        System.out.println("Field2: "+Class2.getField2());
        System.out.println("Field3: "+Class2.getField3());
    }

    private static void changeField(Field field) throws Exception {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, "changed");
    }
}

class Class2 {
    private static final String field1 = "no change"; // constant variable, read access must be inlined
    private static final String field2; // blank final
    private static final String field3; // blank final
    static {
        field2 = "no change";
        field3 = "no change";
    }
    public static String getField1() { return field1; }
    public static String getField2() { return field2; }
    public static String getField3() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
            if (!field3.equals("no change")) {
                return field3;
            }
        }
        return field3;
    }
}
```

It will print out

> ```
> Before:
> Field1: no change
> Field2: no change
> Field3: no change
> Field3: no change
>
> After:
> Field1: no change
> Field2: changed
> Field3: no change
> ```

So the JIT changed (at runtime) the code method `getField3` to no longer access the field `field3` but to load the constant "no change" directly. Since `field3` is declared as final this is a perfectly legal optimization.

If you try to run it with Java 17 it will throw an exception:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers
>   at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2610)
>   at Main.changeField(Main.java:xx)
>   at Main.main(Main.java:xx)
> ```

Comment: @Pshemo are you sure? The JavaDoc for [`Field.setAccessible()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#setAccessible(boolean)) specifically states: _This method cannot be used to enable write access to a non-modifiable final field. The following fields are non-modifiable: static final fields declared in any class or interface_ (and my tests in Java 17 failed accordingly)

Comment: non-static `final` fields are modifiable. You could never reliably [change `static final` fields](https://gist.github.com/DasBrain/ca16053f8e073c8a883bee66302c2fee).

Comment: @ThomasKläger My mistake, in Java 17 we no longer can modify `static final` fields (although IIRC in Java 14 it was still possible - but I may be wrong).

Comment: You could not even modify `static final` fields in Java 8. See my demonstration. Depending on a lot of factors, it may appear to work with Java 8, but that was never supported.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I've added an example that shows how a blank `static final` field can be changed in Java 8 and Java 11. Please note that you absolutely must run it with a Java 8 or Java 11 JVM.

Comment: @ThomasKläger Nope: https://www.online-java.com/EW6ASa4ifN I just added an extra call to `getField2` and added a small loop to `getField2`. It says: "no change".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn thanks for your code. I've included it into the answer to show why changing the field sometimes seems to work and sometimes doesn't work.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn not even every non-`static` field is modifiable. Final fields of hidden classes (which includes the generated classes for lambda expressions), as well as `record` fields are non-modifiable. And, as always, `System.out`, `System.err`, and `System.in` do not count…

Comment: @Holger Yeah. Changing `final` fields is tricky, any should be only done on instances that did not escape and are therefore not visible to other threads. And never change trusted final fields.