# String intern's behaviour?

Tags: java, string

```
String string1="Hello Snehal";
String string2=new String("Hello Snehal");
String string3=string2.intern();


System.out.println("string1==string2  " +  string1==string2);  // false. OK.
System.out.println("string2==string3  " +  string2==string3);  // false. OK.
System.out.println("string1==string3  " +  string1==string3);  // false. why not TRUE?
```

When searched other questions for clarification, e.g. [When should we use intern method of String on String constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855170/when-should-we-use-intern-method-of-string-on-string-constants), still not getting clue about 3rd case.

Comment: `==` has lower precedence than `+`. Consider `a + b == c`, you expect this to be `(a + b) == c` not `a + (b == c)`

Comment: Thanks for quick explanation!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of them are `false`, because what's happening are few checks whether:

- `"string1==string2  " +  string1` refers to `string2` (for the first statement)
- `"string2==string3  " +  string2` refers to `string3` (for the second one)
- `"string1==string3  " +  string1` refers to `string1` (for the last one).

You need to wrap the `stringX == stringY` pieces, because otherwise String concatenation will take place first (as you might already know, the statements in Java are evaluated from left to right and wrapping some of them with brackets `()` gives them priority).

So, having this:

```
System.out.println("string1==string2  " +  (string1==string2)); 
System.out.println("string2==string3  " +  (string2==string3));
System.out.println("string1==string3  " +  (string1==string3));
```

should behave differently and then you should be able to investigate the output.

Answer (score 1):

`String.intern()` on a string will ensure that all strings having same contents share same memory . Refer to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) for more detail.