# string.toUppercase() created a new object in heap or string pool

Tags: java, string, uppercase

If we use `toUpperCase()` method of String class, does it put the object in the heap rather than creating it in the String pool. Below is the code, when I ran, I could infer that newly created string objects are not in String pool.

```
public class Question {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1="abc";
        System.out.println(s1.toUpperCase()==s1.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

Output of the above code return **false**.
I know about "==" and equals() difference but in this question I am wondering why the two created strings are not equal. The only explanation could be that they are not created in the String pool and are two different objects altogether.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: When you create String literals that goes to String pool.  For Everything else a new Object is  created.

Comment: `==` is not compare 2 strings, it compares 2 object containt reference to these 2 strings so 2 object are difference. String object is immutable so I think it will go to String pool. Read more about `immutable vs mutable object`, `string pool vs heap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java automatically interns String literals. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1855183/1448660), but when you use `toUpperCase()` it creates a new instance of the string, using `new String()`, that's why both the objects are different.

Comment: why does it create a new Object rather than returning an interned String?

Comment: documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

The "==" operator compares the value of two object references to check whether they refer to the same String instance, so in this case `toUpperCase()` creates a new instance of String that's why it return false.

On the other hand `equals()` method compares the "**value**" inside String instances irrespective of the two object references refer to the same String instance or not, and so it returns true.