# Why a String do not point to the same object in the String pooled area?

Tags: java, string, object, heap-memory, stack-memory

I know that String is immutable. In the example below a String constant object will be created in String pooled area and `s1` will point to the `"Hello"`. Also `s2` will make a String constant with the same value `"Hello"`.

But I don't understand why `s2` do not point to the first "Hello". From what I understand String "Hello" already exist in the String pooled area and if I create *another* String with this value, it will point to the existing object rather than create another object. For example `s3` points to the same object like `s1`.

I didn't use `new` keyword for `s2`. Why `s2` doesn't point to the same object like s1  and s3?

```
public class DemoApp {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s1 = "Hello";
        String s2 = "Hello friends".substring(0, 5);
        String s3 = "Hello";

        System.out.println(s2);        //Hello
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);  //false
        System.out.println(s1 == s3);  //true
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Hello
false 
true
```

Comment: There are no `s3` and two `s1`...?

Comment: I remember seeing an almost identical question like this involving toUpperCase... (downvoted and deleted, I think)

Comment: [I think here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398042/string-touppercase-created-a-new-object-in-heap-or-string-pool)...

Comment: "I didn't use `new` keyword for s2" well, you didn't use it *explicitly* but it was used internally by `substring` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the implementation of substring method you will see its create a String with the new operator, thus the returned string is not present in the string pool.

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > value.length) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    int subLen = endIndex - beginIndex;
    if (subLen < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(subLen);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == value.length)) ? this
            : new String(value, beginIndex, subLen);
}
```

Replace your code

```
String s2 = "Hello friends".substring(0, 5);
```

with
    String s2 = "Hello friends".substring(0, 5).intern();

you will see its returning true.

Comment: Note that `String.intern()` is generally not advised, used here only to illustrate a point.

Comment: exactly, just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: DO NOT USE ON PRODUCTION CODE

Comment: (unless you know what you're doing!)

Comment: This is how it is implemented, but this doesn't explain why: it is simply less effort to create a new string than it is to putatively create a string and check if it is already in the string pool; in the vast, vast majority of cases, it simply doesn't matter, and in the few cases that do, you've got `intern()`.

Answer (score 0):

Only string literals (and constants at compile-time) are pooled.

The `substring` call computes a new `String` that does not come from the pool. After all, `substring` doesn't know beforehand whether or not its result is already pooled. Therefore it has to allocate space for a new `String`, just in case the result isn't already in the pool. Then, if the space for the result is already allocated, it is wasteful to "check" if that result is already pooled. Hence, you get the behavior you see -- the `substring` result is not pooled, even though it's equal to something else in the pool.

Comment: It is not just literals that are pooled, any compile-time constant expression of `String` type will be in the pool, e.g. `"" + 0`.