# How many objects are created if we call any method like subString() or toUpperCase() on a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, jvm

How many objects are created by the following 2 lines of Java code?

```
String s = new String("Hello");
String s1 = s.toUpperCase();
```

I know toUpperCase() will create a new object in the heap. But I want to know if it will also be placed in the String pool.

Comment: In the title, you ask “How many String objects are created…”, in the body text, you ask “how many objects will be created…”. This is not the same. Further, the last sentence creates an entirely different question.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is ... it depends.

The one thing that we can say with certainty is that neither `toUpperCase()` or `subString()` will place a `String` in the string pool<sup>1</sup>.  The only `String` operation that is specified as (possibly) adding a `String` to the string pool is `intern()`.

We cannot say for certain that `toUpperCase()` and `subString()` will generate a new `String` object.  For example, in Java 11 `str.substring(0)` returns `str` itself.  This is an implementation detail, but the javadocs for many operations are worded so that it would be valid to return `this` ... if `this` satisfied the requirements.

In the cases when a new `String` is created, it is implementation dependent how may objects are created.  A Java string is typically represented as a `String` object with a reference to an backing `char[]` or `byte[]` that represent the string's characters.  But in some Java releases, a backing array can be shared between multiple `String` objects ... under certain circumstances.  And indeed `substring` was one of the methods that would create `String` with shared backing arrays.

Finally, as a commenter pointed out, this stuff is irrelevant to real world Java programming ... in all but the most extreme circumstances.  Normally, you should just let the JVM deal with this kind of stuff.

---

<sup>1 - It is the string pool not the "constant string pool".  The "constant pool" is actually something that exists in class files.  But the string pool may contain strings that do not correspond to Java constants.</sup>

Comment: So `toUpperCase`, as an implementation detail, can potentially return the same object as well?

Comment: In theory, yes.  And in practice, yes in Java 11.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can test it by running the following code.

```java
    String s = new String("Hello");
    String upperS = "HELLO";
    String s1 = s.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(s==s1);  //prints false
    System.out.println(upperS==s1);  //prints false
```

From [§3.10.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-3.html#:%7E:text=a%20string%20literal%20always%20refers%20to%20the%20same%20instance%20of%20class%20String.%20This%20is%20because%20string%20literals%20%2D%20or%2C%20more%20generally%2C%20strings%20that%20are%20the%20values%20of%20constant%20expressions%20(%C2%A715.29)%20%2D%20are%20%22interned%22%20so%20as%20to%20share%20unique%20instances%2C%20as%20if%20by%20execution%20of%20the%20method%20String.intern%20(%C2%A712.5)) of the Java documentation:

> …a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.29) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, as if by execution of the method String.intern (§12.5).

So, the String Pool holds only string literals from the Java source code (expressions like `"abc"`) and strings that have had their `.intern` method called.

In your code the following line creates a String object on the heap, but not a literal in the String Pool.

```java
    String s = new String("Hello");
```

The following line also creates another object in the Heap and doesn't create a literal in the String Pool.

```java
    String s1 = s.toUpperCase();
```

So, in your example. 2 objects will be created in the heap. No new literals will be added to the String Pool.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46398042/string-touppercase-created-a-new-object-in-heap-or-string-pool)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong; the "String Constant pool" is just a section of the heap, specifically for `String` values.
So, what is created in the heap, is the pool you're referring to.

It's +2 `String` objects for `String s = new String("Hello")`.
And, +1 `String` object for `String s1 = s.toUpperCase()`.

Additionally, most IDEs allow you to view the memory during a debugging process.