# Changing private final fields via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, final

```
class WithPrivateFinalField {
    private final String s = "I’m totally safe";
    public String toString() {
        return "s = " + s;
    }
}
WithPrivateFinalField pf = new WithPrivateFinalField();
System.out.println(pf);
Field f = pf.getClass().getDeclaredField("s");
f.setAccessible(true);
System.out.println("f.get(pf): " + f.get(pf));
f.set(pf, "No, you’re not!");
System.out.println(pf);
System.out.println(f.get(pf));
```

Output:

```
s = I’m totally safe
f.get(pf): I’m totally safe
s = I’m totally safe
No, you’re not!
```

Why does it work by this way, can you please explain? The first print tells us that the private "s" field has not been changed, as I expect. But if we get the field via reflection, the second print shows, it is updated.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection/31268945#31268945

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection/31268945#31268945

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection) is more than exhaustive on the topic.

JLS 17.5.3 Subsequent Modification of Final Fields

> Even then, there are a number of complications. If a final field is
> initialized to a compile-time constant in the field declaration,
> changes to the final field may not be observed, since uses of that
> final field are replaced at compile time with the compile-time
> constant.

But, if you read the paragraph above very carefully, you may find a way around here (set the `private final` field in the constructor instead of in the field definition):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WithPrivateFinalField pf = new WithPrivateFinalField();
    System.out.println(pf);
    Field f = pf.getClass().getDeclaredField("s");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println("f.get(pf): " + f.get(pf));
    f.set(pf, "No, you’re not!");
    System.out.println(pf);
    System.out.println("f.get(pf): " + f.get(pf));
  }

  private static class WithPrivateFinalField {
    private final String s;

    public WithPrivateFinalField() {
      this.s = "I’m totally safe";
    }
    public String toString() {
      return "s = " + s;
    }
  }

}
```

The output is then as follows:

```
s = I’m totally safe
f.get(pf): I’m totally safe
s = No, you’re not!
f.get(pf): No, you’re not!
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: +1 - this is the real answer.  The OP's program is causing the JIT compiler's assumption that `s` doesn't change to be invalid.  This is not a compiler bug, since the JLS explicitly warns that "bad things" like this can happen if you modify `final` variables after they have been set.

Comment: @Stephen C: Actually the behavior has nothing to do with *JIT* compiling. It's already the bytecode compiler that replaces the `s` in `return "s = " + s;` with the compile-time constant. This can be demonstrated by making two classes, `A` and `B` so that `A` refers to a constant defined in `B`. Now, changing the constant in `B` and recompiling only `B` will keep the old constant in `A`! Sneaky, but true.

Comment: @Joonas - ok ... but it would also be legitimate for the JIT compiler to do this kind of optimization.

Comment: @Stephen C: Indeed. IMO it would be way *better* if the JIT compiler would do that instead of the bytecode compiler. With the current behavior, you can break someone else's class just by modifying the *value* of a, say, flag constant in your class.

Comment: Should I call `f.setAccessible(true);` after that to restore field modifiers?

Comment: I think you don't have to restore the field accessibility as it is in fact a copy of some Java internal `Field` instance. Such a copy is just for you to use. So if you don't need to read the original `accessible` flag state later on in your code, you don't have to keep and then restore its state.

Comment: not working with java 17

Comment: @Tarik: Can you be more specific? If that was due to the compile time error "non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context", I fixed the code to compile even with JDK17.

Answer (score 18):

This

```
class WithPrivateFinalField {
    private final String s = "I’m totally safe";
    public String toString() {
        return "s = " + s;
    }  
}
```

actually compiles like this:

```
class WithPrivateFinalField {
    private final String s = "I’m totally safe";
    public String toString() {
        return "s = I’m totally safe";
    }  
}
```

That is, **compile-time constants get inlined.** See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377819/are-all-compile-time-constants-inlined) question. The easiest way to avoid inlining is to declare the `String` like this:

```
private final String s = "I’m totally safe".intern();
```

For other types, a trivial method call does the trick:

```
private final int integerConstant = identity(42);
private static int identity(int number) {
    return number;
}
```

Comment: I really like this clear explanation and `intern()` approach, did not know about that before... Thanks.

Comment: Actually, rather use `toString` since it avoids a lookup in the string pool.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a decompile of `WithPrivateFinalField` class file (I put it in a separate class for simplicity):

```
  WithPrivateFinalField();
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [13]
     4  aload_0 [this]
     5  ldc <String "I’m totally safe"> [8]
     7  putfield WithPrivateFinalField.s : java.lang.String [15]
    10  return
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 2]
        [pc: 4, line: 3]
        [pc: 10, line: 2]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 11] local: this index: 0 type: WithPrivateFinalField

  // Method descriptor #22 ()Ljava/lang/String;
  // Stack: 1, Locals: 1
  public java.lang.String toString();
    0  ldc <String "s = I’m totally safe"> [23]
    2  areturn
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 6]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 3] local: this index: 0 type: WithPrivateFinalField
```

Note in the `toString()` method, the constant used at address 0 [`0  ldc <String "s = I’m totally safe"> [23]`] shows the compiler already concatenated the string literal `"s = "` and the private final field `" I’m totally safe"` together in advance and stored it.  The toString() method will always return `"s = I’m totally safe"` regardless of how the instance variable `s` changes.

Answer (score 1):

Being `final`, the compiler expected the value not to change, so it probably hardcoded the string directly into your `toString` method.