# Test Design: How to test a method properly without rewriting it completely?

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I have the following class which contains a hard coded URL that never changes:

```
    public class HttpClient {
        private final String DOWNLOAD_URL = "http://original.url.json";

        public String readJsonDataFromUrl() throws IOException {
            URLConnection urlConnection = getUrlConnection();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();

            String readLine = "";
            while ((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
                content.append(readLine);
            }

            return content.toString();
        }

        private URLConnection getUrlConnection() throws IOException {
            URL jsonLocator = new URL(DOWNLOAD_URL);

            return jsonLocator.openConnection();
        }
    }
```

Now imagine that I'd like to expect the IOException in my test. In my opinion, the only way to do that is to rewrite the complete class in a mock object because of the final variable:

```
public class HttpClientMock extends HttpClient  {
    private final String DOWNLOAD_URL = "http://wrong.test.url.json";

    @Override
    public String readJsonDataFromUrl() throws IOException {
        URLConnection urlConnection = getUrlConnection();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();

        String readLine = "";
        while ((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
            content.append(readLine);
        }

        return content.toString();
    }

    private URLConnection getUrlConnection() throws IOException {
        URL jsonLocator = new URL(DOWNLOAD_URL);
        URLConnection urlConnection = jsonLocator.openConnection();

        return urlConnection;
    }
}
```

But this is somehow far-fetched. If the original methods would be changed, the test results could still be positive because with this attempt, I don't actually test the original class anymore.

How can this be done properly? (I don't want to use a framework just for this one test, so are there any design attempts to solve this in a common way?)

Comment: can you change the original code?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to make it less restrictive by making the private method protected or something. Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Return the download URL from a one line get method and pass it to the other methods in the class.  You can test the other methods by passing bad URLs.

Comment: Good idea, could you post this as answer. If this works fine, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Making protected is actually opening up for changes not restricting. Able to write unit tests easy is a sign of a good design. However:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516381/changing-private-final-fields-via-reflection

Comment: @Bevor I'm not quite sure if such a test even makes sense. Looking at the source code above, it actually does not create and throw a new _IOException_ on its one. Instead the code just passes along IOException to the caller through the _throws declaration_. So what the test case really does is to make sure that the used methods of the standard library throw IOExceptions as expected. Sure a unit test should not be aware of the implementation, but is this test case really worth the effort?

Comment: Basically you are right, but I wasn't exactly sure when the IOException is really thrown so I decided to pass some malformed urls or a supposed proper url like `http://foobarxyzxyzxyz.com` to see if this is really covered. Ok, I could rely on the javadoc, but I feel better to cover all possible errors in tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everybody, but I think that Gilbert Le Blanc's solution is the most preferable for that case which looks like this:

**The original class:**

```
public class HttpClient {
    private final String DOWNLOAD_URL = "http://my.original.json.url";

    public String readJsonDataFromUrl() throws IOException {
        URLConnection urlConnection = getUrlConnection();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();

        String readLine = "";
        while ((readLine = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
            content.append(readLine);
        }

        return content.toString();
    }

    private URLConnection getUrlConnection() throws IOException {
        URL jsonLocator = new URL(getConnectionString());

        return jsonLocator.openConnection();
    }

    protected String getConnectionString()  {
        return DOWNLOAD_URL;
    }
}
```

**The mock object:**

```
public class HttpClientMock extends HttpClient  {
    private String downloadUrl = "http://my.original.json.url";

    public HttpClientMock()  {
        super();
    }

    public HttpClientMock(String downloadUrl)  { 
        this.downloadUrl = downloadUrl;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getConnectionString()  {
        return downloadUrl;
    }
}
```

**And the working tests:**

```
public class HttpClientTest {

    private JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    @Test
    public void readJsonDataFromUrlSucceeds() throws IOException, ParseException {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClientMock();

        String jsonString = httpClient.readJsonDataFromUrl();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject)jsonParser.parse(jsonString);

        assertTrue(jsonObject.size() > 0);
    }

    @Test(expected = IOException.class)
    public void readJsonDataFromMalformedUrlFails() throws IOException, ParseException {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClientMock("http://malformed");

        httpClient.readJsonDataFromUrl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another spin on Gilbert Le Blanc's suggestion, is to make the HttpClient totally ignorant of the URL by injecting it through the constructor.

```
 public class HttpClient {
   private final String url;

   public HttpClient(String url) { this.url = url; }

 }
```

You can hard code the URL (or read from a config) somewhere externally to HttpClient and inject it wherever you instantiate the client.  Then in your test it will be trivial to inject a bad url.

Comment: I already thought about that but this would offer an unnecessary weak point.

Comment: One could parse here any url, and this is absolutely not necessary since the url never changes.

Comment: The fact that you want to test a bad url means that the url can change.  An HttpClient should be able to read from a URL.  Whatever URL it ends up reading from is a dependency.  Testable systems allow you to inject dependencies.  One of the main reasons for this is so you can inject mock components where needed.

Comment: I know what you mean, but see my explanation at Jordan White's posting.