# Java string intern and literal

Tags: java, string, literals

Are the below two pieces of code the same?

```
String foo = "foo";
String foo = new String("foo").intern();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They have the same *end result*, but they are not the same (they'll produce different bytecode; the `new String("foo").intern()` version actually goes through those steps, producing a new string object, then interning it).

Two relevant quotes from `String#intern`:

> When the `intern` method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this `String` object as determined by the `equals(Object)` method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this `String` object is added to the pool and a reference to this `String` object is returned.
>
> All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned.

So the *end result* is the same: A variable referencing the interned string "foo".

Comment: In this case, new String("foo").intern();, the newly created string object is not added to the heap right?

Comment: @foo: It probably is, but it's immediately available for reclamation again by the GC, as by the end of the expression there are no outstanding references to it. And I expect an optimizing JVM (like Sun/Oracle's HotSpot) optimizes the `new String("foo").intern()` away on the first pass anyway, once it's noted that there are no side-effects to calling the constructor. Or it may not because barring this being in a tight loop, it doesn't meet the threshold of being worth it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was wondering why would anyone ever use new String("foo") idiom to initialize strings when if I do it that way, I create two objects, one on the heap and the other in the pool. Is there any advantage of using new String("foo") that I am missing other than an uniform pattern to initialize all objects in Java?

Comment: @foo: The only advantage I can think of is if you *don't* use `intern`, you know that the string *reference* is unique even if the string contents are not. Not many use-cases for that, I wouldn't think, but since `new String("foo") != "foo"` by definition, it could be handy on some occasions. Not many, though, I wouldn't have thought.

Answer (score 4):

[`public String intern()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29)

> It follows that for any two strings s
>   and t, `s.intern() == t.intern()` is
>   true if and only if `s.equals(t)` is
>   `true`.

So I believe the answer is yes, although the second method will have to search through the pool.

**EDIT**

*As sugegsted by T.J. Crowder*

> When the intern method is invoked, if
>   the pool already contains a string
>   equal to this String object as
>   determined by the equals(Object)
>   method, then the string from the pool
>   is returned. Otherwise, this String
>   object is added to the pool and a
>   reference to this String object is
>   returned.
>
> All literal strings and string-valued
>   constant expressions are interned.

Comment: I think the more relevant two quotes are: *"When the `intern` method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this `String` object as determined by the `equals(Object)` method, then the string from the pool is returned. Otherwise, this `String` object is added to the pool and a reference to this `String` object is returned."* and *"All literal strings and string-valued constant expressions are interned."*

Comment: Now this should be per JVM basis right? So if i have a cluster than it will behave differently.

Answer (score 3):

The first one i.e.

```
    String foo = "foo";
```

in this line, we are creating a String using String literals. That means the string is automatically saved in String Constant pool.

In the 2nd one , i.e. -

```
    String foo = new String("foo").intern();
```

Here we are creating a String using new String() & then manually saving it to the String constant pool. If we didn't have mentiones intern() , it would not have saved in the String constant pool.

For more clarification, please refer to this link -

http://javacodingtutorial.blogspot.com/2013/12/comparing-string-objects-intern-other.html

Comment: This answer can't be more wrong. To say that the second snippet won't have the String in the pool without calling `intern()` is obviously wrong, because it ___still___ uses the literal `"foo"`. The effect of `intern` is in this context, that the call to the String constructor doesn't matter anymore and `foo` refers to the literal version `"foo"` and not the newly constructed one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are same. Basically `intern()` returns a representation of a string that is unique across the VM. This means you can use `==` instead of `.equals()` to compare the strings, saving on performance.

Answer (score 0):

> Explicitly constructing a new String
>   object initialized to a literal
>   produces a non-interned
>   String. (Invoking intern() on this
>   String would return a reference to the
>   String from the intern table.)

Taken from : http://javatechniques.com/public/java/docs/basics/string-equality.html