# Syntactic sugar for strings in Java

Tags: java, string, comparison

Is

```
String test1 = "something"
```

just syntactic sugar for

```
String test2 = new String("something")
```

and if it is why do the following lines return different results? (I know the difference between using the == operator and the equals() method)

```
System.out.println(test1 == "something");     // returns true
System.out.println(test2 == "something");     // returns false
```

Or is there something more?

Comment: This question is asked every day.

Comment: Funny, I could not find an exact dupe for this one.

Comment: They all get closed and removed anyway. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: well found.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java ; It's not syntactic sugar. How you a string literal be syntactic sugar for something that requires using a string literal? Also if that was syntactic sugar, any program using a string literal wouldn't run, since `"something"` is syntactic sugar for `new String("something")`, which is syntactic sugar for `new String(new String("something"))` ... which would lead to infinite recursion depth and therefore a StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

All string literals will be "interned" as the java files being compiled.

Have a look of this question: [Java string intern and literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777131/java-string-intern-and-literal)