# Why does my multi-jar application seem to not notice changes in a JAR containing one class of only fields?

Tags: java, jar, jvm

I have an application  that has one executable JAR, which uses a library of other JARs. When I update a library JAR, the users close their program and open it again, and the new JARS are used. However, I have one JAR that contains only one class, that contains only fields. When this JAR is replaced on its own, the values in the fields from the old JAR appear to be used in the program.

The old JAR is gone from the file system at this point, so I'm a little confused as to where the values are coming from. My current solution is to update another JAR that is using the problematic JAR, but I'm not sure why this works so I'm looking for any insight that may be available.

Comment: That fields, are they possible `static final` constants?

Comment: Yes, all of the fields I have experienced this problem are `public static final`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constants in java code can be inlined by the compiler. Example:

```
public class A {
    public static final String STR = "foo";
}

public class B {
    public static void main(final String... args) {
        System.out.println(A.STR);
    }
}
```

If you change STR to "bar" and recompile A, B will still print "foo" when running. The solution is to also recompile and update the code that uses the constants.

Also see [Are all compile-time constants inlined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/377819/are-all-compile-time-constants-inlined)

Comment: This is exactly it, seems obvious now that you say it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The values of these static fields are probably held in RAM after your program closes. If you rename the package or the class containing these fields I bet it would work when you modify the values and restart. This isn't a good solution, just a little confirmation that the values are being cached. 
I suggest that you not have a class with just field values. If you want to separate these values from the rest of your code then you can use a properties file if the fields are easily representable as strings. You could also make them fields in some other class.

Comment: I do not think that this is the case, as most fields are changed properly when updating JARs. A properties file may be a good option, but I have found the other answer provided a preferable solution.