# Final static String compilation issue. Any suggestions how to avoid?

Tags: java, string, ant, static

I have a situation where I have few files having final static String variables (constants). Now these variables are used in many files using the classname.variable. These files are present in different jars. First jar contains the constants, second jar will contain the files that are using the constants. It is understood that when java compilation happens for the files which are using the constants, classname.variable will be replaced by the constant itself during compilation.

Now, suppose I change the value of a constant and build the first jar, there will not be any compilation issue nor runtime issue in the application. But in the second jar, previous constant will be there in the class file. How do I avoid this? Please provide suggestions. I'm building jars using ANT.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, I heard this from my Senior manager at work and this issue seems to be creating lot of problem. He wanted me to analyze this and find a solution. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Seems that you're right. It surprised me. Anyway, solution can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377819/are-all-compile-time-constants-inlined).

Comment: try to use  "volatile final static String", then java will inforce the use of the newest value

Answer (score 3):

The value copying behavior only applies to *compile-time constants*. A variable is a compile-time constant if it is declared `final` *and* initialized with a compile-time constant. Therefore you can enforce a variable to be no compile-time constant by not initializing it:

```
public static final String CONSTANT_BUT_NOT_COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANT;

static {
    CONSTANT_BUT_NOT_COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANT = "the value being constant at runtime";
}
```

Here, the variable is not *initialized* with the constant value but *assigned* after the declaration. Therefore it is not a compile-time constant and thus, it’s value never copied at compile time. It is still immutable at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the final modifier.
Or make sure to rebuild the second jar.