# Does the JLS require inlining of final String constants?

Tags: java, java-8, language-lawyer, javac, jls

I ran into an issue while manipulating some bytecode, where a certain `final` `String` constant was not inlined by the java compiler (Java 8), see the example below:

```
public class MyTest
{
  private static final String ENABLED  = "Y";
  private static final String DISABLED = "N";

  private static boolean isEnabled(String key) {
      return key.equals("A");
  }

  private static String getString(String key, String value) {
      return key + value;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String flag = getString("F", isEnabled("A") ? ENABLED : DISABLED);
    System.out.println(flag);

    String flag2 = getString("F", isEnabled("A") ? ENABLED : DISABLED);
    System.out.println(flag2);
  }
}
```

Resulting bytecode with javac (1.8.0_101)

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]) throws java.lang.Exception;
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=2, locals=3, args_size=1
         0: ldc           #8                  // String F
         2: ldc           #2                  // String A
         4: invokestatic  #9                  // Method isEnabled:(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
         7: ifeq          16
        10: getstatic     #10                 // Field ENABLED:Ljava/lang/String;
        13: goto          19
        16: getstatic     #11                 // Field DISABLED:Ljava/lang/String;
        19: invokestatic  #12                 // Method getString:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        22: astore_1
        23: getstatic     #13                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        26: aload_1
        27: invokevirtual #14                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        30: ldc           #8                  // String F
        32: ldc           #2                  // String A
        34: invokestatic  #9                  // Method isEnabled:(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
        37: ifeq          46
        40: getstatic     #10                 // Field ENABLED:Ljava/lang/String;
        43: goto          49
        46: getstatic     #11                 // Field DISABLED:Ljava/lang/String;
        49: invokestatic  #12                 // Method getString:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
        52: astore_2
        53: getstatic     #13                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        56: aload_2
        57: invokevirtual #14                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        60: return
```

You can see that the second time the fields `ENABLED` and `DISABLED` are being accessed, the compiler did not inline their values (using `ldc`), but instead used `getstatic` to access the field directly. Testing it with other compilers (Java 7, Eclipse) did not trigger the same behavior and the constants were always inlined.

Can this be considered a compiler bug, or is it allowed to *not* inline string constants all the time according to the JLS?

Comment: Define 'inlined'. The JLS require *pooling*. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Inlining means to replace the getstatic instruction with an instruction that directly pushes the constant value onto the stack, e.g. ldc in case of strings, or iconst_X/bipush/sipush/... in case of integer primitives, ...

Comment: The JLS does not mention *any* bytecode-instructions nor the concept of a constant-pool - it describes the *language*.

Comment: Sure, I wanted to give a concrete example, based on actual instructions. I understand that the JLS does not talk about byte-code level instructions itself in this matter.

Comment: @piet.t: I removed the byte code tag, as the language specification does indeed not deal with byte code. However, the *behavior* is defined without ambiguity, which allows to answer the question.

Comment: Well spotted. This is indeed a bug, and it's been fixed by the fix to [JDK-8066871](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8066871) which was integrated in JDK 9 and backported to JDK 1.8.0_102 -- which is 1.8.0_101 plus a patch set. Note that JDK-8066871 has different symptoms, but the same fix corrects that error as well as the one described here.

Comment: I just filed a bug report (JI-9043578) as I did not find a related entry in the bug database. I guess it can be closed then.

Comment: @T.Neidhart Thanks for filing the bug! I've linked them together as duplicates. I think we probably need a regression test in this area, as this bug was present in the first release of JDK 8 and in two years' worth of updates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the “inlining” behavior is mandated by the specification:

> #### [13.1. The Form of a Binary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1)
>
> …
>
> 3. A reference to a field that is a constant variable (§4.12.4) must be resolved at compile time to the value `V` denoted by the constant variable's initializer.
>
>    If such a field is `static`, then no reference to the field should be present in the code in a binary file, including the class or interface which declared the field. Such a field must always appear to have been initialized (§12.4.2); the default initial value for the field (if different than `V`) must never be observed.
>
>    If such a field is non-`static`, then no reference to the field should be present in the code in a binary file, except in the class containing the field. (It will be a class rather than an interface, since an interface has only `static` fields.) The class should have code to set the field's value to `V` during instance creation (§12.5).

Note, how this precisely addresses you scenario: “If such a field is `static`, then no reference to the field should be present in the code in a binary file, *including the class or interface which declared the field*”.

In other words, if you encounter a compiler not adhering to this, you found a compiler bug.

---

As an addendum, the starting point for finding this information was:

> #### [4.12.4. final Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)
>
> …
>
> A *constant variable* is a `final` variable of primitive type or type `String` that is initialized with a constant expression ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)). Whether a variable is a constant variable or not may have implications with respect to class initialization ([§12.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)), binary compatibility ([§13.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.1), [§13.4.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.9)), and definite assignment ([§16 (Definite Assignment)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-16.html)).

Comment: Thanks a lot that is exactly what I was looking for, so this confirms that the observed behavior is indeed a compiler bug.

Comment: I checked all those references except binary compatibilty :)