# Java Reflection: setting a final field isn't working

Tags: java, reflection

So, I made a `ReflectUtil` class with some useful methods that allow me to access the java reflection API in a fast and simple way.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection) the method `forceCall` can change the value of a private and final field.

This example works absolutely fine:

```java
ReflectUtil.forceCall(Boolean.class, null, "FALSE", true);
System.out.println(String.format("Everything is %s", false));
```

The output is: `Everything is true` (so my method is working).

But this just isn't working (it also doesn't work if i try it without my ReflectUtil class):

```java
public class JustForTestingPurposes {
    private static final String field = "no";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ReflectUtil.forceCall(JustForTestingPurposes.class, null, "field", "yes");
        System.out.println(String.format("Is this working? %s", field));
    }

}
```

The output is: `Is this working? no`

I thought, maybe it's because of the way how java assigns values, so I added a 1 sec sleep before executing the code in the main method, with no success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/4417924

Comment: @Jason I think you didn't read my post well. I even referred to this post you linked.

Comment: Have you read this comment under accepted answer in question linked by you at start of your post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection#comment30350617_3301720?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how constants work in java.

When a java program is compiled, all references to a compile-time-constant (using a literal or maybe `<Classname>.class` or similar)are replaced with the constant itself.

You should be able to bypass this by assigning it to the return value of a method or using the `new` operator(the following example contains both):

```
private static final String field = getNo();
private String getNo(){
    return new String("no");
}
```

Comment: Hm, didn't know that. That explains a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Either the method or the `new` would do. The key phrase is *compile-time constant*.

Comment: Yes, java does a few optimisations :)

Comment: `<Classname>.class` is not a compile-time constant. And, as TomHawtin-tackline said, there is no need for `new String("no")`. Using `private String getNo(){ return "no"; }` would work as well. In fact, just declaring the variable as `private static final String field = "no".toString();` would be enough. But unlike `final` instance fields, changing `static final` fields via runtime is an unsupported feature, even when using Reflection. It's not guaranteed to work at all.

Comment: Yea but I am not sure what will be optimized away

Comment: This has nothing to do with optimizations. The behavior of compile-time constants is precisely specified in the JLS. See [Does the JLS require inlining of final String constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39386014/2711488) and the definition of [constant expressions in JLS, §15.28.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)